How to list all the commit messages for a specific file?
I need to list all committed subjects for a specific file. If possible, I would like them ordered by date. The git log will show detailed commit messages, but I'm not sure how to filter only commit messages from it. Also is it possible to format the output of the git log?
Also, this should work with GitHub pages and GitHub actions

Does this answer your question? How to list all commits that changed a specific file?

git log --follow --format="%as: %s" -- <path to file>
Here %as will show the date in iso short format
%s will show commit subject
--format will format the string according to our needs
more about formatting and string placeholders can be seen by git log --help
